Gnome Flashback (Metacity) dual displays/monitors and workspaces
I'm using Gnome Flashback (Metacity) on Ubuntu 22.04. I connected a second monitor and have it set up as "join displays". Now whenever I switch workspaces it switches on both displays. There's an option in "multitasking" settings that goes "workspaces on primary display only" but it doesn't work in Gnome Flashback (it does work with regular ubuntu and gnome classic). Is there a way to make it work like this in flashback?
Thanks

Metacity does not support that. Answer to your question, sadly, is no.
